# How to use with start-process with variable for the filepath? (Windows10/Powershell)

Tags: windows, powershell

Please consider the code below (inside a .ps1 script)

```
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $env:windows\security -Filter "my-app-here*.*" | Sort-Object -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$file=$env:windows+"\security\"+$latest.name
start-process $file
```

this works fine.

If I try to simplify the code to:

```
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $env:windows\security -Filter "my-app-here*.*" | Sort-Object -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
start-process $env:windows+"\security\"+$latest.name
```

I get the error message:

```
start-process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? Thanks a lot

Comment: What about: `start-process "$($env:windows)\security\$latest.name"`

Comment: That looks like a string vs object issue (in the 1st example $file is a string, in the 2nd you are smashing objects together in a way that has a nice toString() but isn't itself an easy string.  Try `start-process "$($env:windows)\security\$($latest.name)` instead

Comment: Just noticed @LotPings beat me to the punch, but you do need to parenthesis enclose `$latest.name` as `$($latest.name)` to get the desired result. >`start-process "$($env:windows)\security\$($latest.name)"`

Comment: @Ruscal Yepp, overlooked that one.